# How do I have undefined defaultValue with react-hook-form?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have this form using a Controller from react-hook-form:

```
<Controller name="myField" control={control} as={(
 <>
   <input type="radio" value="true" />
   <input type="radio" value="false" />
 </>
)}/>
```

It is complaining:
"myField is missing in the 'defaultValue' prop of either its Controller"

But...the thing is. The value needs to be undefined. The user needs to select a value and otherwise it will get a validation error on the form. They need to pick one or the other and we do not want to have a default "yes" or "no" here.

How do I get rid of these warnings? According the docs from react-hook-form I am doing something wrong since it says: "Setting defaultValue inline or at useForm can not be undefined.". But...that's exactly what I want.

Edit:
To clearify a bit more. I have a schema validation using yup, like this:

```
yup.object().shape({
 myField: yup.boolean().required()
});
```

Now, when I use a defaultValue set to an empty string I need to add a transform: `.transform((x) => (x === '' ? undefined : x))`
And that's something I would like to avoid because it get's messy real quick.

Comment: Why don't you just set defaultValue to empty string or something?

Comment: That seems odd to me. An empty string is not one of the allowed values. It needs to be either one of the two options or 'undefined'. Like..not set.

I have the same issue with a <select> that has a 'placeholder' option. That option will resolve into 'undefined'. So it needs to be one of the options or undefined. And show an error if the placeholder is selected and the field is required.

Comment: It is warning, not error so it is not critical. If empty string works and doesn't brake your code why not

Comment: But warning mean something right. And I now get them a lot potentially clouding other warnings that I want to resolve. Using an empty string seems like a bit of a hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to not use `undefined` here and instead use `null` for your `defaultValue`. `null` means no value as on the other hand `undefined` has the meaning that the property/variable has not been defined yet.

If you really need to use `undefined` for your radio input, you can just use `register` as your radio input is a native HTML `<input />` element.

[image: Edit React Hook Form - Basic (forked)]

Comment: Thanks...let me check this out

Comment: Was my suggestion able to solve your problem?

Comment: Yes it does but it also has some side effects in our project since we need to use the .nullable() method in the yup schema, resulting in a null type when sending it to the backend. We like to stick with just undefined so we decided to just ignore the warnings.